# Network app works in simulator, but not on the iPhone

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, objective-c, tcp

I am currently writing a game for the iPhone, which communicates with a C++ server through TCP/IP to exchange user data, friend lists, sound files and more. The server and the client use the same structs when reading/writing on the socket:

```
//Packet used for small stuff
typedef struct small_packet {
    int msgtype:8;
    int size:16;
    int extra:16;
    int following:24;
    char data1[64];
    char data2[64];
} packet;

//Packet used for files
typedef struct file_packet {
    int msgtype:8; //For partial file packet this should be 0x02
    int size:16;
    int extra:16;
    int following:24;
    char data1[64];
    char fileBuffer[1024];
} filePacket;

//Used for file headers
typedef struct filehead_packet {
    int msgtype:8;
    int size:16;
    int extra:16;
    int following:24;
    char data1[64];
    int fileid;
    char rest[60];
} fileheadPacket;
```

When in simulator mode, the app works perfectly and communicates with the server over the internet. When run on the iPhone however, it doesn't work as well. A login packet uses the small packet (upper struct). The msgtype is 0x01, the size is sizeof(packet), following is 0, extra is 0, data1 holds the username, and data2 holds the calculated password hash value. It appears the server gets the 0x01, as it treats the incoming message as a login request. It also gets the size. The problem appears when copying the username and password hash from data1 and data2.

When cout'ing on the server, it seems like the first three letters of the username is not read by the server. When I try to login with say "username", the server gets "rname", and the PWHash has a similar offset (3*sizeof(char)). This only happens when I run the app on the actual unit, and not in simulator.

I admit I have recently modified the layout of the structs -- up until now the extra-field has only had 8 bits, and I had an additional int:8 field after the following-field. I have updated the structs with this info on both the client and the server, and run a clean+rebuild on both, so I don't see why it would matter. And as a matter of fact, 8+8=16, which is the new size of the extra-field, so the data1 and data2 fields should start at the same offset in memory as they used to with the old structs.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! I am very stuck on this and it's really annoying not knowing what's wrong at all... It could be endianness for all I know (the iPhone is bytesexual, isn't it?), but if that's the case I have no idea how the server interprets a 0x01 as a 0x01... oh well. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The server is an actual remote server as I understand, right? Because if it's a `localhost`, you need to use the `IP` of the localhost, rather than using `localhost` in your app.

Comment: Just a thought: Could it be a utf8 problem? I mean is your username actually 'username' or is it something written in Norwegian?

Comment: The server is remote and I have the full ipv4 address hard coded into my app. @gWiz: my username consists of only plain letters from the English alphabet. As a matter of fact, the client only accepts usernames in [a...z].

Comment: I suggest logging a sizeof for all structs - it's possible the packing is different mac/ios. If so clang probably has some directive to pack the struct exactly like the mac does. Also it's good practice to use the macros to turn all numerics to network order (see ntoh macros).

Comment: Thanks @DavidH! I will try this when I get back to work tonight. I've skipped htons/ntohs in this case because both machines work in network endian order, but I agree it's good practice to use them and I will add it to my programs later. Different packing is something I haven't thought of -- thanks, I'll see if that's the case when I get back to work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest logging a sizeof for all structs - it's possible the packing is different mac/ios. If so clang probably has some directive to pack the struct exactly like the mac does. Also it's good practice to use the macros to turn all numerics to network order (see ntoh macros).

Even more a problem is that your use of bitfields is highly non-portable, and theoretically could change with a compiler update. I'd suggest using a different set of "transmission" structs for transmitter and receiver, using uint64_t values in them for the flags:

```
typedef struct small_packet {
    uint64_t flags;
    char data1[64];
    char data2[64];
} packet;
```

You could write really simple C code to map your "real" structs to and from the ones used for transmission. K&R C warns against using bitfields across platforms (I just looked it up :-)).

Comment: But that would require me to rewrite a major part of my net-com modules. Oh well, thanks anyway :)

Comment: As a temporary fix to see if the problem was actually the bitfielding I removed the length flags for all the fields in the structs, both server side and client side. This made all the ints 32 bits long, and that obviously leads to some unnecessary traffic of '\0'-bits, but now the server communicates well with the client, and "username" is actually read as "username". Thank you @DavidH for pointing me in the right direction :)